# How to define a custom function in groovy, using JSR-223 API to integrate with java

Tags: java, groovy, jsr223

if i use GroovyShell, it is just like this:

```
CompilerConfiguration cfg = new CompilerConfiguration()
cfg.setScriptBaseClass(CustomScript.class.getName())

GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(cfg)
```

in which "CustomScript" is my custom class with my custom functions.

How can i do this when i use JSR-223 API to integrate groovy with java?

I didn't find any interfaces in JSR-223 API or GroovyScriptEngineImpl.

Answer (score 0):

On GroovyScriptEngine you'd just do this:

```
CompilerConfiguration cfg = new CompilerConfiguration()
cfg.setScriptBaseClass(CustomScript.class.getName())

GroovyScriptEngine engine = new GroovyScriptEngine(...)
engine.setConfig( cfg )
```

JSR-223 doesn't really have an equivalent of that.  You could bind your Java object instance into a global variable to expose those APIs to whatever scripting language you want.  Doing this:

ScriptEngine engine = ...
engine.put("system", new SystemSupport() )

But that'd look like this to your script:

```
system.someApiMethod()
```

But you won't be able to subclass CustomScript transparently to expose methods "globally".  Not all scripting languages work from an Object only point of view as Java does.  Take Javascript for example. How would that work subclassing a Java object in JS which doesn't support typical OO? And JSR-223 was very much conceived with the Javascript point of view in mind.

For practical purposes you may want to evaluate whether JSR-233 API compliance is a must and adapt to it, or just cut bait and go with a specific scripting engine like Groovy.  But I might go the DSL route over subclassing an object as I think it's more flexible and expressive.